# Attach JProfiler when JVM Starts or Profile Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, jvm, jprofiler

We have a job server that is periodically executing groovy scripts. They are not compiled.

I would like `JProfiler` to attach to *any* JVM when it starts up, record profiling information and then save the snapshot to some directory that we may look over the results at another time. Is there any way to do this?

Alternatively, I could manually start the script from inside JProfiler and get the results that way. However, it doesn't seem to be aware of Groovy scripts and I can only find a way to launch *compiled* Groovy code. Is there any way to launch a script and profile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bin/jpenable` command line utility with the `--offline` switch (see the output of `jpenable --help`) to run a pre-configured offline profiling session. That session should contain triggers for recording data and saving a snapshot.

> However, it doesn't seem to be aware of Groovy scripts

You would have to add the groovy classes to the list of profiled classes on the "Filter Settings" tab of the session settings. However, unless the script is compiled, you would not see the method names in the call tree, so it would not be very useful.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even if I run a pre-configured offline profiling session, it needs to be set-up for an _already running_ JVM instance? I would like it to attach to _any_ JVM that starts up on a target machine. Is this possible?

Comment: To profile a JVM at startup, you have to add the -agentpath parameter as given by the remote integration wizard to the JVM.